# Is it possible to prevent an object from rotating in Corona SDK?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, game-physics

I guess its pretty self explainatory, I need to know if its possible to disable/prevent rotation for an object when the physics engine is enabled. The object is affected by gravity as it falls down most the time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is, simply use:

```
object.isFixedRotation = true
```

To "pause" rotation use:

```
object.angularVelocity = 0
```

at any given point.

Comment: first add the object to the physics object and then set the field: `physics.addBody( object,"dynamic" )` and then `object.isFixedRotation = true`